# Better Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook

I want to develop facebook iframe application and I have working experience of .NET and PHP. Can anyone help me figure out which is best SDK to use ( .NET or PHP). Which is better to use?

Answer (score 1):

If you're best with PHP, I'd recommend using the official [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/), otherwise you may want to check out [Microsoft's Facebook SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574.aspx) or [Facebook's C# SDK](https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't has a chance to mess around with any .net SDK...

But, as far as Facebook SDK's go - the php one is quite satisfactory. I would try it first, then if you are not happy with it - go to the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP is better than other, beacuse facebook is already using php in a development process...

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend based on your command on the programming language. Both have SDKs to use facebook.
    If you have good knowlege in both, better suggestive is PHP over .NET